# How can I make triangle using mapping nodes?

Tags: node-editor

I have a custom texture and need it to appear in triangle shape I know that I can use few Mapper nodes to make triangle or circle or any other shape but I don't know what other nodes I need to use to make a formula for triangle. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: final]

I'm "math disabled" ;) so this is my dumb version of triangle.

You can change **Rotation in Mapping** nodes as well as **values in math nodes** to achieve different triangles.

What it does is basically creating 3 black&white planes and then rotating them and offsetting.

[image: triangle]

Comment: I was trying with precise values in Mapper node, but your solution is simpler and faster. Thanks!

Comment: @Anna I'm still trying to make it with proper math formula, but I don't know which should I use ;)